# PostSharp stackoverflow on aspect

Tags: stack-overflow, postsharp

Aspect class looks like this:

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;
  using System.Diagnostics;
  using PostSharp.Aspects;

  namespace GlobalExceptionHandler
  {

[Serializable]
class MyDebugger : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("METHOD ENTRY: " + args.Method.Name + "(" + args.Arguments.GetArgument(0) + ")");
    }
    public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception at: " + args.Method.Name + "()");
        args.FlowBehavior = FlowBehavior.Continue;
    }
}
```

}

I am applying the aspect to mscorlib assembly to system namespace but excluding the console class which i thought was causing the stackoverflow on my aspect as it uses a Console.WriteLine to print the log.

```
[assembly: GlobalExceptionHandler.MyDebugger(AttributeTargetAssemblies = "mscorlib", AttributeTargetTypes = "System.Console", AttributeExclude = true, AttributePriority = 100000)]

[assembly: GlobalExceptionHandler.MyDebugger(AttributeTargetAssemblies = "mscorlib", AttributeTargetTypes = "System.*")]
```

And im still getting the stackoverflow exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression in the aspect code where you add several strings using "+" is actually emitted as a call to `String.Concat` method by C# compiler. So you get this code in the `OnEntry`:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Concat("METHOD ENTRY: ", args.Method.Name, "(", args.Arguments.GetArgument(0), ")"));
```

To avoid recursion you can exclude `System.String` class in the same way you did with `System.Console`. However, in general case it's better to add a thread-static flag to your aspect that will serve to stop recursive calls.

```
[Serializable]
class MyDebugger : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static bool isLogging;

    public override void OnEntry( MethodExecutionArgs args )
    {
        if ( isLogging ) return;

        isLogging = true;
        Console.WriteLine( "METHOD ENTRY: " + args.Method.Name + "(" + args.Arguments.GetArgument( 0 ) + ")" );
        isLogging = false;
    }

    public override void OnException( MethodExecutionArgs args )
    {
        if ( isLogging ) return;

        isLogging = true;
        Console.WriteLine( "Exception at: " + args.Method.Name + "()" );
        args.FlowBehavior = FlowBehavior.Continue;
        isLogging = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! so basically string.concat gets called when i add two strings with the "+" which then calls the on entry again because string.concat is not excluded from the aspect and it does this endlessly so the compiler detects it and throws the stackoverflow exception. Makes sense! By the way whats the correct usage for attribute priority in this case?

Comment: You're welcome! With the priority it's important that adding the aspect on all types is ordered before removing the aspect from specific types. So, your approach is correct. More info at http://doc.postsharp.net/multicast-override